# Testing the redux store using Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, redux, jestjs, redux-thunk

I've set up the following function to configure a Redux store

```
const configureStore = (initialState) => {
  console.log(initialState);
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(
      thunkMiddleware
    )
  );

  console.log(store.getState());
  return store;
};
```

Now, running this from my normal app entry point, the console logs show, for example:

```
-> Initial state = { Test: "test" }
-> (Store gets created)
-> Store state = { Test: "test" }
```

Thats good, and as expected. I'm then trying to confirm this behaviour with the following Jest test

```
it("should set the supplied initial state", () => {
    const initialState = {
      TestState: "Test"
    };

    const store = configureStore(initialState);
    expect(store.getState()).toEqual({
      TestState: "Test"
    });
  });
```

This test is failing, as store.getState() is returning undefined. I can see the console logs from the configureStore function, and its showing:

```
-> Initial state = { Test: "test" }
-> (Store gets created)
-> Store state = undefined
```

Why is the behaviour different? Is it that Jest is mocking the createStore function? I've read that Jest no longer auto-mocks dependencies, so why would this be the case? I'm new to Jest unit testing, so any light that can be shed on this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I do realise that I'm essentially just testing a Redux function, which is probably very unnecessary. Regardless, I'd like to understand the testing behaviour that's causing this issue.

Second Edit: Writing my own createStore function as follows makes the test pass:

```
const createStore = (reducer, initState, middleware) => {
  return {
    getState: () => (initState)
  };
};
```

But this still doesn't answer why the redux createStore function is behaving differently in the test environment.

Comment: It's most likely an issue with your root reducer as all actions go through this, including the action fired when redux instantiates. Can you  include your reduer code in the question?

Comment: At this stage my root reducer simply returns the state. const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  return state;
};

Comment: Ok, that is fine. Next up, what does your thunkMiddleware function look like?

Comment: It's the standard thunk middleware, imported from here: [link](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.js)

Comment: Also, removing the middleware hasn't solved the issue.

Comment: I've finally had some time to recreate your test. What you have works fine for me. The code I used to test is [here](https://gist.github.com/8enSmith/c03895030979973f1234402168220032). I am using jest@20.0.4.

Comment: Ben! Thank you for taking the time to do that, it's helped me solve the issue.  I should have actually figured it out after your first comment, which was right on the money. I'll post the answer now for anyone else who might make the same rookie mistake I did.

Comment: No problem. I should've posted me comment as an answer! ;)

Comment: Full credit to you mate. I'd be happy to accept your answer if you want to do a quick writeup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All actions go through your:

```
rootReducer
```

including the action fired when Redux instantiates e.g. the initial action has the type '@@redux/INIT'.

So if you ever get an unexpected state always check that your reducer is behaving as expected.

As you [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45411457/203371), the reducer was not behaving as expected as the mock instance was not being preserved across tests.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out thanks to [Ben Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203371/ben-smith).

When I ran the test by itself, it passed. The problem was I had this test right before it:

```
it("should set the root reducer", () => {
    rootReducer.default = jest.fn();
    const store = configureStore();
    store.dispatch({
      type: "TestAction"
    });
    expect(rootReducer.default).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

I was mocking the reducer, and for some reason I thought the reducer wouldn't stay mocked across the two tests, but obviously it did. To solve it, I just stored the unmocked reducer before mocking it, and then added this cleanup to the end of the tests that do mock the reducer function:

```
//Cleanup - unmock reducer
rootReducer.default = actualReducer;
```